# Drawing a self-erasing path with CGContextRef

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, cgcontext

I would like to draw a "disappearing stroke" on a `UIImageView,` which follows a touch event and self-erases after a fixed time delay. Here's what I have in my ViewController.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
   CGPoint lp = lastPoint;

   UIColor *color = [UIColor blackColor];
   [self drawLine:5 from:lastPoint to:currentPoint color:color blend:kCGBlendModeNormal];

   double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
   dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
   dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
      [self drawLine:brush from:lp to:currentPoint color:[UIColor clearColor] blend:kCGBlendModeClear];
   });

   lastPoint = currentPoint;
}

- (void)drawLine:(CGFloat)width from:(CGPoint)from to:(CGPoint)to color:(UIColor*)color blend:(CGBlendMode)mode {

   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

   [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

   CGContextMoveToPoint(context, from.x, from.y);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, to.x, to.y);
   CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
   CGContextSetLineWidth(context, width);
   CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
   CGContextSetBlendMode(context, mode);
   CGContextStrokePath(context);

   self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   [self.tempDrawImage setAlpha:1];
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

The draw phase works nicely, but there are a couple problems with the subsequent erase phase.

1. While the line "fill" is correctly cleared, a thin stroke around the path remains.
2. The "erase phase" is choppy, nowhere near as smooth as the drawing phase. My best guess is that this is due to the cost of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` run in `dispatch_after`.

Is there a better approach to drawing a self-erasing line?

BONUS: What I'd really like is for the path to "shrink and vanish." In other words, after the delay, rather than just clearing the stroked path, I'd like to have it shrink from 5pt to 0pt while simultaneously fading out the opacity.

Comment: Creating a graphics context, drawing into it, and capturing the image is a very expensive way to do this. I would suggest instead using a custom subclass of UIView and overriding `drawRect`. You can then do your drawing commands directly into the current graphics context. You can issue a setNeedsDisplay on the view in order to trigger the view to be updated. You might want to increase the stroke width slightly (try 1/2 point larger) for the erase phase than for the draw phase.

Comment: @DuncanC thanks man. Yeah I just realized increasing stroke width can fix the ghost-outline issue. I'll try your drawInRect suggestion. Cheers!

Comment: the erase-strategy is not a great idea... if you draw a loopy sorta thing where a newer line crosses an older line, and the old line gets erased, the new line will get erased as well at the intersection.

Comment: Not drawInRect, `drawRect()`. That's the method that gets called on a custom view when it's time to update it's contents. In truth you're probably better off drawing the entire view in it's new state at each update, rather than trying to erase the old path segments. (@spinalwrap's point about self-crossing paths is one of the problems you'll face with the erasing approach.)

Comment: If I was doing this I think I'd use a CAShapeLayer and animate changes to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a lot of great answers here. I think the ideal solution is to use OpenGL, as it'll inevitably be the most performant and provide the most flexibility in terms of sprites, trails, and other interesting visual effects.

My application is a remote controller of sorts, designed to simply provide a small visual aid to track motion, rather than leave persistent or high fidelity strokes. As such, I ended up creating a simple subclass of `UIView` which uses CoreGraphics to draw a `UIBezierPath`. I'll eventually replace this quick-fix solution with an OpenGL solution.

The implementation I used is far from perfect, as it leaves behind white paths which interfere with future strokes, until the user lifts their touch, which resets the canvas. I've posted the solution I used [here](https://github.com/CaptainStiggz/zrandom/tree/master/CGSelfErase), in case anyone might find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would just let the view draw continuously with 60 Hz, and each time draw the entire line using points stored in an array. This way, if you remove the oldest points from the array, they will not be drawn anymore.

to hook up your view to display refresh rate (60 Hz), try this:

```
displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(update)];
[displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Store an age property along with each point, then just loop over the array and remove points which are older than your threshold.

e.g.

```
@interface AgingPoint <NSObject>
@property CGPoint point;
@property NSTimeInterval birthdate;
@end

// ..... later, in the draw call

NSTimeInterval now = CACurrentMediaTime();

AgingPoint *p = [AgingPoint new];
p.point = touchlocation; // get yr touch
p.birthdate = now;

// remove old points 
while(myPoints.count && now - [myPoints[0] birthdate] > 1)
{
     [myPoints removeObjectAtIndex: 0];
}
myPoints.add(p);

if(myPoints.count < 2)
    return;

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath path];
[path moveToPoint: [myPoints[0] point]];
for (int i = 1; i < myPoints.count; i++)
{
    [path lineToPoint: [myPoints[i] point];
}

[path stroke];
```

So on each draw call, make a new bezierpath, move to the first point, then add lines to all other points. Finally, stroke the line.

To implement the "shrinking" line, you could draw just short lines between consecutive pairs of points in your array, and use the age property to calculate stroke width. This is not perfect, as the individual segments will have the same width at start and end point, but it's a start.

Important: If you are going to draw a lot of points, performance will become an issue. This kind of path rendering with Quartz is not exactly tuned to render real fast. In fact, it is very, very slow.

Cocoa arrays and objects are also not very fast.

If you run into performance issues and you want to continue this project, look into OpenGL rendering. You will be able to have this run a lot faster with plain C structs pushed into your GPU.